# Link juice from a 301 redirect question

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, ranking, link-juice

I've just finished redesigning the website and had some new URLs that didn't match up to old ones.

I did a 301 redirect to those pages. Now the old and the new page are ranking first and second in google (2 results ranking instead of 1 previously).

My theory is that since the redirected URL is ranking, it hasn't been crawled yet, so the new page is not getting any juice from the redirect.

What I want What will happen if I redirect my old page to another URL. Will the ranking for the new URL remain?

Comment: Only ever redirect when you relevant pages to the next.... i.e iphone.html to `/iphone/` not `iphone.html` to `/technology/`. The juice is passed when the old one is dropped from the index, this can take several days but waiting a couple of weeks sometimes isn't uncommon. So as long as your 'CURL' test confirms a header status of 301 redirect, wait.